# bash pipe output to multiple processes

Tags: bash

bash pipe question

I have seen similar questions with answers but I am asking about the very basic case of piping output to multiple processes. For example, I want to output fortune to cowsay and (espeak &). I have a solution (following) but there must be a simpler, more elegant way.

joshua@joshua-HP-Pavilion-dv8-Notebook-PC ~ $ cat .bashrc

```
(fortune -a > ~/tmp) && echo && (cat ~/tmp |cowsay -W65) && (cat ~/tmp | espeak &)
rm ~/tmp
```

Output:

```
  ___________________________________________
/ I ain't got no quarrel with them Viet Congs. \
|                                              |
\ -- Muhammad Ali                              /
 ----------------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
joshua@joshua-HP-Pavilion-dv8-Notebook-PC ~ $
```

Plus the audio from espeak running as a background process (| espeak &).
My solution redirects output to a file (~/tmp), performs the actions, then deletes ~/tmp. Why can't I do, e.g.:

```
fortune -a | (cowsay -W70 && espeak &)
```

?
I've tried many variations, here's my history of attempts:

```
  501     fortune -a | (cowsay -W70 && espeak &)
  502     fortune -a | (cowsay -W70 && espeak)
  503     fortune -a | (cowsay -W70 | espeak)
  504     fortune -a | (cowsay -W70;  espeak)
  505     fortune -a | (espeak | cowsay -W70; espeak)
  506     fortune -a | (espeak | cowsay -W70)
  507     fortune -a | (espeak & | cowsay -W70)
  508     fortune -a | (espeak & && cowsay -W70)
  509     fortune -a | (espeak && cowsay -W70)
  510  fortune -a | (espeak && cowsay -W70)
  511  (fortune |cowsay -W65) && (cat ~/tmp | espeak &)
  512  (fortune |cowsay -W65) && ( espeak &)
  513  (fortune |cowsay -W65) && espeak &
  514  fortune | (cowsay -W65 && espeak &)
  515  history
```

Also, this is my first attempt at posting a question. Constructive feedback welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee` in conjunction with process substitution.

```
fortune -a | tee >(cowsay -W65) >(espeak)
```

Comment: Having read `man tee` I found this to work pretty well:
`fortune -a |tee >(cowsay -W65) >(espeak) >-`
The `>-` prevents a copy to STDOUT. 
The only remaining issue I now have is my prompt comes before the cowsay output.
I have tried `&& echo` is various places to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to suppress standard out; usually I use `> /dev/null`, but `>-` is shorter. The prompt appearing is due to the asynchronous nature of the process substitutions. Something longer like `mkfifo foo bar; fortune -a | tee foo > bar; cowsay -W65 < foo; espeak < bar; rm foo bar` might work. This replaces the process substitutions with explicit uses of named pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not calling `fortune -a once` and store it's results in variable?

```
# Store "fortune" output in a variable
fortune_result=$(fortune -a)

# Use that variable as input for multiple processes
(cowsay -W70 && espeak &) <<< "$fortune_result"
(cowsay -W70 && espeak) <<< "$fortune_result"
(cowsay -W70 | espeak) <<< "$fortune_result"
```

Comment: I like the variable idea. Avoiding disk I/O, especially for a few lines of text, is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

First of all kudos for the question and I'm glad you tried before coming here and asking. I had a lot of fun when I saw the output :) - Upvoted.

My best result so far is (and I think is more simpler than yours)

```
fortune -a > a.txt | cowsay && espeak -f a.txt && rm a.txt
```

The logic I used was:

- fortune to a file
- pipe the result to cowsay && espeak
- remove the file.

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak it a bit because I want a prompt immediately while epseak speaks. This worked:

`fortune -a > a.txt && (espeak -f a.txt &) && cat a.txt |cowsay -W65 && rm a.txt`

With yours I was getting the speech, but an empty cowsay bubble! I also needed to move the espeak to the front of the command because a.txt was getting deleted before espeak could find it.

Answer (score 1):

`tee` commands can be chained together:

```
fortune | tee cowsay | tee espeak
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. First you save fortune result, than you print cowsay with text you saved before and at the end espeak is used.

```
clear;save=$(fortune);cowsay -f gnu <<< "$save"; espeak <<< "$save"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful replies!

The best solution for my use case I have found so far is this:

```
fortune -a > a.txt && (espeak -f a.txt &) && cat a.txt |cowsay -W65 && rm a.txt
```

because it presents the command prompt after the text and speech and looks nicest (output-wise). This is in my .bashrc so I want it to look nice when I start a terminal shell. Not much different than my original attempt!

Doing this any way other than a temp file shows the command prompt first, which looks ugly. i.e.:

```
joshua@joshua ~ $  _________________________________________
/ Be wary of strong drink. It can make    \
| you shoot at tax collectors and miss.   |
|                                         |
\ -- Lazarus Long, "Time Enough for Love" /
 -----------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Personal responses found in replies. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

I use xclip

***fortune | xclip ; xclip -o | cowsay ; xclip -o | espeak -ves &***

xclip needs to be installed first.

*fortune | xclip*         > read text from fortune.

*xclip -o | cowsay*       -> send the text to cowsay.

*xclip -o | speak -ves &* 
                        -> send the text to espeak and give you the prompt.